# Joining three table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables like below.

```
Courses:
Id Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D

Prices:
Id CId Price
1   1   200
2   2   150
3   3   500
4   4   300

Payment:
Id  CId
1    1
2    4
```

If a record of payment for Course record exists, then Price should be -1.  I want to get result like below:

```
Id Name Price
1   A    -1
2   B    150
3   C    500
4   D     -1
```

How should I query mysql?

Comment: What did you try so far

Comment: I joined Courses and Prices tables and use it., but I don't have any idea how to join three tables

Comment: you can add that code in question

Comment: SELECT * FROM courses 
    CASE WHEN payment.IdOn IS NOT NULL 
    THEN -1 END AS Price
    LEFT JOIN payment ON payment.IdOn=courses.Id
    INNER JOIN prices ON prices.IdOn=courses.Id
    WHERE prices.On=0 AND prices.CatId=? AND courses.Status=2 AND (payment.On=0 OR payment.On IS NULL)

Comment: why is price not in course table?

Comment: Because it's simpled table table. In real database there complex relation between them

Comment: You join 3 tables the same way you join 2 tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT c.Id, c.name, 
CASE WHEN pa.id IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE pr.price
END as Price
FROM Courses c
LEFT JOIN Prices pr 
ON c.Id = pr.CId
LEFT JOIN Payment pa
ON c.id = pa.CId;
```

OR

```
SELECT c.Id, c.name, 
CASE WHEN pa.id IS NULL THEN pr.price ELSE -1 
END as Price
FROM Courses c
LEFT JOIN Prices pr 
ON c.Id = pr.CId
LEFT JOIN Payment pa
ON c.id = pa.CId;
```

Comment: This is already there in the answers. Why post something same?

Comment: @P.Jairaj something different from other answer

Comment: It gives duplicate records

Answer (score 1):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6f26/6)** Thanks to @Barmar

```
SELECT C.ID, C.NAME, CASE WHEN pay.CId IS NULL THEN P.PRICE
                          ELSE -1
                     END as Price
FROM Courses C
JOIN Prices P 
  ON C.Id = P.CId
LEFT JOIN Payment pay
  ON C.id = pay.CId
ORDER BY P.id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Id | Name | Price |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 |    A |    -1 |
|  2 |    B |   150 |
|  3 |    C |   500 |
|  4 |    D |    -1 |
```

Comment: instead of `Case` you can use `COALESCE`

Comment: I'll try and give feedback

Comment: Case is used in stored procedures. Try to just execute the above code in the sqlfiddle. Gives an error. @Ali

Comment: @P.Jairaj `CASE` can also be used in expressions. The above should work.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN P.Price IS NULL THEN -1    ELSE P.Price END AS Price     FROM cour' at line

Comment: @P.Jairaj The code above had a typo, the comma after `C.ID` was a dot.

Comment: @Barmar it should not be P.PRICE in the case, it should be WHEN PAY.CID IS NULL. As p.price is never null. Your fiddle is giving wrong output too. It never shows -1.

Comment: Thanks @VR46 you were right. But I cant use `COALESCE` now there was a mistake on code.

Comment: SqlFiddle Updated to fix the wrong fieldname, and now the correct output is include it on the answer

Comment: I used your answer but gave "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN P.Price IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE P.Price END AS Price FROM cour' at line" error. I tried another answer, I think maybe I was in wrong in a place. I thank you for your trying,

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
select c.id, c.Name, IF(pm.CId is null, p.Price, -1) as Price
from Prices p left join Payment pm
on p.CId = pm.CId 
inner join Courses c 
on p.CId = c.id
order by c.id
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1b715/3

Comment: I think you should have all the `INNER JOIN`s before the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Any reason for that?

Comment: See http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/11/mixing-inner-outer-joins-sql.aspx

Comment: returned duplicate records

Comment: @Ali every table is one to one right? No repetition of CId right?

Comment: it will give duplicates only if CId is repeated in some table

Comment: @Barmar Even when may be better for reading is OK, because is `LEFT JOIN` A with B and then `JOIN` A with C so the final result is the same.

Comment: @P.Jairaj Maybe would be better if you use the OP data to create the fiddle. There is a function in SqlFiddle look on the top tool bar for `Text to DDL`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT p.id,c.NAME, CASE WHEN p.cid=e.cid THEN -1 ELSE p.price END AS price
FROM prices p
LEFT JOIN courses c 
ON c.id=p.ID
LEFT JOIN payment e 
ON p.cid=e.cid

Comment: Nice first answer sam! One thing to try in the future is to enclose code in tick marks. You can also click the "{ }" button above the textbox when entering your answer. This helps make your answer more readable, and it's more likely to marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for you trying